# Show video on Raspberry pi in .net

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, .net-core, mono, electron.net

I need to implement showing video (from file or stream, it does not matter) using Raspberry pi, and requirement is to use c# programming language (mono or preferably .net core). Video needs to be shown in full screen on a monitor/TV pi is connected to.

However, I can't find any useful material on this topic. What would be the best approach? Mono WinForms seems obsolete, and Electron or Avalonia with .net core do not seem to support this. Also UWP on Windows IoT also does not seem to support this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: showing video using Raspberry [using] c# programming language"...Why? Why is C# a requirement? Why can't you simply install a normal video player (vlc?) on the raspberry pi and point it to a url or a file?

Comment: c# is clients requirement, mostly for the shared code for communication with the API. It will be preforming multiple different tasks, not simply playing video. Actually showing video will be rare, it will mostly show notifications, images, etc. However, the only issue is showing video...